# How to put text using JButtons in the JTextField which has focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, jtextfield

I've made two `JTextField` controls named `textfield1` and `textfield2` in Java. I've also made a number pad using `JButton` components and added an `ActionListener` to each of them. Now I want the corresponding number to be inserted in the text field which has currently the focus. The **problem** is that, when a number pad button is pressed, the focus immediately changes to that button. So, `getFocusOwner` doesn't work here.

How it could be resolved?

Comment: Declare a `JTextField lastFocused;` as a class attribute. Add a focus listener to each text field. As the focus leaves the field, call `lastFocused = thisButton;`. In the action listener, get a reference to `lastFocused` & have at it.

Comment: Got it. A lot of Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it even though I mistakenly wrote `lastFocused = thisButton;` instead of `lastFocused = thisTextField;`. Nice going! :)